# mysql won't import table as unicode even tho all variables are set to unicode

Tags: mysql, utf

I have just updated my cnf properties to add the following:

```
init_connect                    = 'SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci; SET NAMES utf8;'
character-set-client            = utf8
character-set-server            = utf8
collation-server                = utf8_unicode_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

My system variables after restarting mysql:

```
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
```

So then I ran the following query to find a table that I knew had been built in utf_general_ci:

```
select t.table_name, c.column_name,round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) 'Size in MB',count(c.column_name), c.character_set_name,c.collation_name 
from columns c
inner join tables t on t.table_schema=c.table_schema and t.table_name=c.table_name
where t.table_schema='db' and 
(c.collation_name like '%general%' or c.character_set_name like '%general%') and 
(c.column_type like 'varchar%' or c.column_type like 'text') and 
t.table_collation not like '%latin%' and t.table_name in ('table_name') group by t.table_name, c.column_name;
```

So I took a dump of the table and reimported it into my database, but it stays in utf8_general_ci!!?!?!??

Why is this? I know if I run an alter it will change it, but why didn't the dump and load resolve the problem?

Additionally, when I run an alter to convert to utf8_unicode_ci, all the columns in the table have "COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci" listed in them.

Comment: What was your dump command sequence?

Comment: mysqldump -p db table > table.sql and then on the import I used mysql -p db < table.sql

Comment: Look in your `table.sql`: does it explicitly set `utf8_general_ci`?

Comment: It does not explicitly state this in the table.sql file.